# using select box as navigation and when select option it selected

Tags: angular

I'm using select box as navigation in angular 7. And I want it selected on page it goes. But the problem is it not working as expected.

this my code

html file

```
<select name="navi"  (change)="navigateTo($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="target">
<option value="null" [selected]="target === null" disabled>select for navigate</option>
<option value="/profile" [selected]="target === '/profile'">Account/Profile</option>
<option value="/summary" [selected]="target === '/summary'">Summary </option>
<option value="/user" [selected]="target === '/user'">User</option>
</select>
```

ts file

```
target:any;
navigateTo(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.ngOnInit()
        this.router.navigate([value]);
        this.target = value
        console.log(value )
    }
    return false;

}
```

Hope you all can help..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular provides a router, use @angular/router and configure an app-routing.module.ts, then you can use in your application this code:

```
<select name="navi">
  <option routerLink='/profile' routerLinkActive='active-link'>Account/Profile</option>
  <option routerLink='/summary' routerLinkActive='active-link'>Summary </option>
  <option routerLink='/user' routerLinkActive='active-link'>User</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry but I think if you use routerLinkActive property it should works as you expected. Remember you set active-link class in your css file and give the desired styles. Or give the default selected class into routerLinkActive property.

Comment: So many many sorry... I misunderstood your answer...Thank you so much dude for your explanation..